# PHP - Re-sizing Image

Tags: php, image, image-processing

the stated code is to copy images from URL, please let me know how to re-size the image by 250x250.

required size:

width  =250
height =250

```
<?php
file_put_contents('tmp.jpg', file_get_contents('http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/3603.jpg'));
?>
```

regards,

Comment: Make use of the PHP GD library.

Comment: Please, use google before you ask a question billion times discussed over the internet

Comment: sorry zerkms...i am not using any other website but stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tutorial to see how you can use a class to resize, scale and save image  ... @ 
http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: This does not directly answer what Fou has asked. I think he wants to know how to buffer the image into a variable first.